# palindrome - how to make main method call the boolean method?

Tags: java

I am trying to get user input and determine if the word is a palindrome or not. The main method should be where all of the print statements are placed.

```
package help;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Help {
    public static Scanner user_input;

    public static void main(String[] args, Iterable<String> lines) {
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        user_input=new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public static boolean istPalindrom(char[] word) {
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = word.length - 1;
        while (i2 > i1) {
            if (word[i1] != word[i2]) {
                return false;
            }
            ++i1;
            --i2;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want it to say

```
if true then System.out.println(The word is a palindrome.)
else System.out.println(The word is not a palindrome.)
```

I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Do you mean just `if (istPalindrome(user_input)) { ... }`?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args, Iterable<String> lines) even possible?

Comment: You need to call the istPaindrom from your main method. Something like if (istPalindrome(user_input) {..})

Comment: I am not sure exactly what I mean, sadly. I was looking at Boolean method examples after using google, but I can't get mine to work. If the method is true, print .... but if the message is false, print..... is what I am trying to get.

Comment: @tiffany do you get any error?

Comment: @KickButtowski, it's for another program. and yes, it is working.

Comment: @tiffany what do you mean?

Comment: @KickButtowski I meant to say, it's for another method, and it worked for that method. But, now I am trying to add this Boolean thing to main method, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I can't spot any error in istPalindrom (not at a frist glance) but where do you call it????

Comment: @the "is this even possible" comment

Comment: @gyro I don't have an error. I was just wondering how to go about making my main method print "this is a palindrome" if the boolean returns true for the user input while making it print "this is not a palindrome" if false is returned. I don't know what to add to the main method to make it do that.

Comment: You will never get an error if you omit to call your function. As of now, there are lot's of answers. So many that the problem is to filter out the wrong ones. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your palindrome test looks good once you fix the indentation, but it's named oddly in English. You have a `Scanner`, so you can get lines of input. Then call `toCharArray()` on the `String` to get the `char[]` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        if (isPalindrome(line.toCharArray())) {
            System.out.printf("The word %s is a palindrome.%n", line);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("The word %s is not a palindrome.%n", line);
        }
    }

}

public static boolean isPalindrome(char[] word) {
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = word.length - 1;
    while (i2 > i1) {
        if (word[i1] != word[i2]) {
            return false;
        }
        ++i1;
        --i2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It says "you can accept an answer in two 2 minutes." I will press the check mark over your answer when I can.

Comment: @KickButtowski I didn't write the above palindrome test. OP did and included it in the post. I did change the spelling.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch To me , it does not help the op at all. you could have suggested some point so op could go and research, but we can agree to disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines into main:

```
if (isPalindrome(user_input))
System.out.println ("The word is a palindrome.");

else
System.out.println("The word is not a palindrome.");
```

Note: Try to make your indentation better in order to make code easily understandable and for visual purposes :)

Comment: Those lines are already in the `while` loop. Indentation is terrible. Also, I renamed the function in my answer. Where did you get `isPalindrome`? Finally, `istPalindrom` takes a `char[]`.

Comment: You are very welcome, you can mark it as correct answer to make it useful for other people who may have same kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work:

```
public static void main(String[] args, Iterable<String> lines) {

    user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    String word = user_input.nextLine();

    if(istPalindrome(word.toCharArray()){
        System.out.println("The word is a palindrome");

    }else{
        System.out.println("The word is not a palindrome");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for palindrome as simple as this if you want to use it !

```
public static boolean isPalindrom(String word) {
    if(new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString().equals(word)){
        System.out.println("The word is a palindrome.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The word is not a palindrome.");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion for future ... lesser lines of code lesser the chances for bugs if you can achieve something by inbuilt function then you should use them rather then recreating the wheel !